# Beginner JS exercise: Change Maker

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am  in the process of learning JavaScript, and have hit a roadblock with an exercise. I'm trying to make a change maker app, and can't figure out how to successfully add an `if`/`else` statement. I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance. I have everything working, but when I try to add the `if`/`else` statement that restricts the input to 0-99, it breaks. I am getting an error that says `cents` is not defined. Is it my placement? Is the code wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
var processEntry = function() {
  var entry = $("cents").value; // get user entry
  var cents = parseInt(entry); // parse entry
  makeChange(cents);
  $("cents").focus();
};
if (!isNaN(cents) || cents < 100 || cents > 0) {
  var makeChange = function(cents) {
    var quarters = parseInt(cents / 25); // get number of quarters
    var dimes = parseInt(((cents - (quarters * 25)) / 10)); // get number of dimes
    var nickels = parseInt(((cents - (quarters * 25)) - (dimes * 10)) / 5); // get number of nickels
    var pennies = parseInt(((cents - (quarters * 25)) - (dimes * 10)) - (nickels * 5)); // get number of pennies
    // display the results of the calculations
    $("quarters").value = quarters;
    $("dimes").value = dimes;
    $("nickels").value = nickels;
    $("pennies").value = pennies;
  };
} else {
  alert("Please enter a number between 0-99")
}
window.onload = function() {
  $("calculate").onclick = processEntry;
  $("cents").focus();
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
  margin-top: 0;
}

main {
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Change Calculator</h1>
  <label>Enter amount of change due (0-99):</label>
  <input type="text" id="cents" />
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" name="calculate" id="calculate" /><br><br>
  <label>Quarters:</label>
  <input type="text" id="quarters" disabled><br>
  <label>Dimes:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dimes" disabled><br>
  <label>Nickels:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nickels" disabled><br>
  <label>Pennies:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pennies" disabled><br>
</main>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: `cents` is local to the `processEntry` function and is not available outside that scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point at which you reference `cents`, it has not been defined.

Since you’re just starting with programming, you should be aware that the statements defined in a function have no affect until the function is run. In your case, the `cents =`… statement has not been run , because the `processEntry` function has not been executed, at the time your `if` statement refers to `cents`, so you are getting the error.

Even if you called `processEntry` first, it would not work, as written, because `cents` is declared to be local to the function. It’d have to be global (always a bad idea) or the value should be returned for use by the caller of the function.

Add the following before the end of `processEntry`:

```
return cents;
```

Then you can simply add the following before your `if` statement:

```
var cents = processEntry();
```

Heh… now, looking at it closer, it looks like you should move the entire `if`… conditional to within `processEntry`. Then what I said, above needn’t be done *and* the code would do what you’re expecting!

Comment: Thank you SO much! Got it working with this help. Greatly appreciated!